# How to create model classes through Entity Framework 6 scaffolding

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have created a data access layer using data first entity framework 6. I want to create models based on these SQL server tables. I tried the following command when I ran it on the cmd prompt after navigating to the Models folder of an Asp.Net Web API project:

```
dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold "Integrated Security=SSPI;Initial Catalog=EmployeeDB;Data 
Source=XYZ;" Microsoft.EntityFramework.SqlServer -o Models
```

But it throws the following error:
Could not execute because the specified command or file was not found.
Possible reasons for this include:

- You misspelled a built-in dotnet command.
- You intended to execute a .NET program, but dotnet-ef does not exist.
- You intended to run a global tool, but a dotnet-prefixed executable with this name could not be found on the PATH.

However similar syntax works for EF Core.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For EF 6 Classic, you can use the tooling built into Visual Studio.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/modeling/code-first/workflows/existing-database